# truffle console: can not paste information into the console

Tags: truffle

Whenever I use the truffle console, I'm not able to paste information from outside the console. This mean that I always have to manually type my contract address, etc. .

However I'm able to copy information from the console.

Does someone experience this ? Do you know how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use right click and paste. It works for me.